# How to add a class in jquery when different attribute value changes?

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, dom

I am working on a html code as shown below. The screen-shot beneath the code belong to the class ***schedule-action-bar*** from the code below.  (removed ct, at nt from the code at this moment in order to minimize my question)

```
<div class="schedule-wrapper" id="js-schedule-wrapper" data-timezone="nt">    <!-- It changes to pt, mt, and et --> 
   <div class="schedule-action-bar" onclick="timezoneCheck()">
      <div class="schedule-timezone-filter">
         Select your timezone:            
         <ul id="js-timezone-picker">
            <li>
               <button id="js-time-pt" class="" data-timezone="pt">PT</button>
            </li>
            <li>
               <button id="js-time-mt" class="" data-timezone="mt">MT</button>
            </li>
            <li>
               <button id="js-time-et" class="" data-timezone="et">ET</button>
            </li>
         </ul>
      </div>
   </div>
   <!-- want to add this class -->
   <!--
   <div class="schedule-date-bar">
      April 12            
   </div>
   -->
   <div class="schedule-show">
      <div class="schedule-show-time">
         <time datetime="21:00 11-04-2019" data-timezone="pt">21:00</time>
         <time datetime="22:00 11-04-2019" data-timezone="mt">22:00</time>
         <time datetime="00:00 12-04-2019" data-timezone="et">00:00</time>
      </div>
   </div>
   <!-- .schedule-show -->
</div>
```

Screenshot:

[image]

**Problem Statement:**

When different timezone is selected from the UI (in the screenshot), the value 
of `data-timezone` changes to pt, mt and et at Line#A. What I want  to do now is to add a  `<div class="schedule-date-bar"> <!-- whatever date belong to the respective timezone --> </div>` before the `schedule-show` class

```
<script>
    function timezoneCheck() {
        jQuery(function ($) {
            $("#js-schedule-wrapper").click(function () {
                if ($('#js-schedule-wrapper').attr('data-timezone') === 'et') {

                } else if ($('#js-schedule-wrapper').attr('data-timezone') === 'pt') {

                } else if ($('#js-schedule-wrapper').attr('data-timezone') === 'mt') {

                } 
            })
        })
    }
</script>
```

This is what I have tried above but more need to be done.

Comment: Why are you binding the click event to `#js-schedule-wrapper` instead of the buttons? In your example you're checking the timezone data attribute of the wrapper each time which never changes, so that doesn't make a lot of sense.

Comment: @j08691 This is the [website](http://www.cpac.ca/en/full-schedule/) which I am working on. If I bind on buttons, that function will show everywhere on the dom so I thought not a good idea to do that.

Comment: @j08691 In it, when different timezone is selected some shows are not showing in proper date.

Comment: I don't understand what you mean by "that function will show everywhere on the dom". If you mean binding to something like `$('button')` then yes, but you don't need to do that, but you could do `$('#js-timezone-picker button')`

Comment: @j08691 can you explain me in an answer ? Comments can be confusing.

Comment: I'm not sure what it is that you're after. For example, how would you get `April 12` in `<div class="schedule-date-bar">`? I don't know where you're getting `whatever date belong to the respective timezone`

Comment: @j08691 Did you have a look at the website ? It will give you a much idea. Some shows are not showing up in proper dates.